# How do I express a list of numbers as the numbers multiplying themselves

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist

For example,  I have the number 60 where I create a list of its prime factors . prime_numbers = [5,3,2,2].
I want to use this list to express the number 60 as  5 * 3 * 2 * 2
Thus the output would be : 60 = 5 * 3 * 2 * 2
Example 2: prime_number = [5,5] . The output would be : 25 = 5 * 5

I tried doing :

```
for i in prime_numbers:
    print(i, end="*")
```

but the output looks like this: 5 * 3 * 2 *2 *
Can someone help please.

Comment: You can use `join` instead of a loop: `' * '.join(str(n) for n in prime_numbers)`

Comment: `sep=` as mentioned above is not a drop-in replacement in your code, but you can do: `print(*prime_numbers, sep=" * ")`

Comment: @Mark Thank you very much. It worked in both cases.  but why when i use: print(prime_numbers, sep=" * ") instead of print(*prime_numbers, sep=" * ") , it doesnt work anymore?

Comment: Right, `print(*prime_numbers)` spreads the list out as arguments to `print()`. It is like calling `print(5, 3, 2, 2)` with 4 arguments. The `sep=` argument in that case works But calling `print(prime_numbers)` is the same as passing a list `print([5, 3, 2, 2])` which is only a single argument. There's nothing to separate in that case.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is like below. I hope it helps.

```
prime_numbers = [5,3,2,2]
mult = 1
for number in prime_numbers:
    mult = mult * number
print(mult, end=" = ")
for i in range(len(prime_numbers)):
    if i == len(prime_numbers) - 1:
        print(prime_numbers[i])
    else:
        print(prime_numbers[i], end=" * ")
```

`>> 60 = 5 * 3 * 2 * 2`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).